# Button refusing to stay put in scrolling div

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

I have a number of buttons in a `div` that refused to stay in a fixed position when the `div` scrolls, and I cannot see why. I have done this elsewhere so I should be able to do it, but I'm going around in circles today.

I have isolated enough of the application to reproduce it easily. It places a `div` in the centre of the screen and puts a small quit button in the top-right. I want the button (and all my others) to remain fixed relative to the `div`. What am I missing?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Scroll</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<style>
div.dt-baseContainer {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 300px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}

div.dt-container {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 3px solid royalblue;
    text-align: center;
}

button.dt-quit {
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: inherit;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

</head>
<div class='dt-baseContainer dt-container' id='dt_container'>
sdfsdf1<br>sdfsdf2<br>sdfsdf3<br>sdfsdf4<br>sdfsdf5<br>sdfsdf6<br>sdfsdf7<br>sdfsdf8<br>sdfsdf9<br>sdfsdf10<br>
sdfsdf11<br>sdfsdf12<br>sdfsdf13<br>sdfsdf14<br>sdfsdf15<br>sdfsdf16<br>sdfsdf17<br>sdfsdf18<br>sdfsdf19<br>sdfsdf20<br>
sdfsdf20<br>sdfsdf21<br>sdfsdf22<br>sdfsdf23<br>sdfsdf24<br>sdfsdf25<br>sdfsdf26<br>sdfsdf27<br>sdfsdf28<br>sdfsdf30<br>
<button id='dt_quit' class='dt-quit' title='Stop'>X</button>

</div>

</html>
```

[Edited] Of course, `position:fixed;` is not relevant unless it's fixed relative to the screen so I removed the mention. But I c=still cannot get this simple thing to work.

Comment: I have experienced that `transform` most of the time kills position fixed. Try removing transform and check

Comment: I didn't know that, but then I would have problems positioning the container in the same way.

Comment: @Tushar, I variations that size and position the window in vw/vh/% units (instead of the transform) but the button still moves. I think this must be something very basic that I'm doing wrong. I also removed the reference to position:fixed as it should be stationary relative to the div and not the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I hate having to answer my own question, but this was me being silly ... of course.

The suggestion above that my `transform` was the problem is a red herring. It is basically not possible to fix an element relative to its container in a scrolling flow.

The solution was to put both my scrolling `div` and my buttons inside an extra containing non-scrolling `div`. Not only does this make sense -- the container encapsulates both scrolling and non-scrolling content without having to put the latter inside the former -- but my initial code was very nearly there.

Taking my existing `dt-baseContainer` class and putting it on an outer `div` fixes the problem.